# Use Array of Values to Filter JSON?

Tags: prisma

Having an array of manufacturerID's, how can I exclude results by the id's in the array?

Is this possible on a JSON field?

```
 {
            Manufacturer: {
              path: ["manufacturerID"],
              not: { in: ["28", "266", "213", "234"] },
            },
          },
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't not appear to be possible, so I have gone with:

```
 NOT: {
          OR: [
            { Manufacturer: { path: ["manufacturerID"], equals: "28" } },
            { Manufacturer: { path: ["manufacturerID"], equals: "266" } },
            { Manufacturer: { path: ["manufacturerID"], equals: "213" } },
            { Manufacturer: { path: ["manufacturerID"], equals: "234" } },
          ],
        },
```